# Python TypeError: object() takes no parameters error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python. I'm following "Learn Python In The Hard Way". In Exercise 40, I tried to write a short code but got an error. Please help me :(

**Source**

```
class showInfo(object):
    'Initialize a classL'
    def __int__(self, name, phone, age):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age

def showName(self):
    print("Name: "+self.name)
def showAge(self):
    print("Age: "+self.age)
def showPhone(self):
    print("Phone: "+self.phone)

emp1 = showInfo("JJJ")

emp1.showName()
```

**Debug**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "classes.py", line 15, in <module>
    emp1 = showInfo("JJJ")
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cause is that `__init__` is misspelled :-)

After that, there will be a different error message because `showInfo("JJJ")` only passes in one parameter when three are needed `showInfo(somename, somephone, someage)`.

After that, there will be yet one more message because the last three methods are not properly indented under the class definition.

Here is the fixed-up code:

```
class showInfo(object):
    'Initialize a classL'
    def __init__(self, name, phone, age):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.age = age

    def showName(self):
        print("Name: "+self.name)

    def showAge(self):
        print("Age: "+self.age)

    def showPhone(self):
        print("Phone: "+self.phone)

emp1 = showInfo("Tom", "555-1212", 21)
emp1.showName()
```

This outputs:

```
Name: Tom
```

Comment: Also, titlecase should be used for defining classname. class ShowInfo(object).